# Jasper compiler error when using SUM method

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm using the Jasper built-in SUM function in a cell of a table.
It should sum the content of other cells (in the example I'm using a single cell, but the output is pretty much the same adding multiple cells).

The jrxml is:

```
<jr:column width="49" uuid="e6595bc8-b46e-4bbe-85a2-7ea9526fce83">
 <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
  <jr:columnHeader style="Table 2_CH" height="20">
    <staticText>
     <reportElement x="2" y="0" width="47" height="20" uuid="af5e8305-5cdf-41ad-b827-80f0ca14771c"/>
     <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
     <text><![CDATA[Nr. Prest.]]></text>
    </staticText>
  </jr:columnHeader>
  <jr:detailCell style="Table 2_TD" height="30">
   <textField>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="49" height="30" uuid="8cc69012-6972-470a-92f4-e735f8d006d8"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[SUM($F{1})]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
  </jr:detailCell>
</jr:column>
```

In Jasper Studio is working correctly, but when I try to compile the report using maven plugin or using the JasperCompileManager it returns these errors

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
1. The method SUM(Integer) is undefined for the type report1_dataset1_1389172627824_411632
            value = SUM(((java.lang.Integer)field_j49.getValue())); //$JR_EXPR_ID=41$
                    <->
2. The method SUM(Integer) is undefined for the type report1_dataset1_1389172627824_411632
            value = SUM(((java.lang.Integer)field_j49.getOldValue())); //$JR_EXPR_ID=41$
                    <->
3. The method SUM(Integer) is undefined for the type report1_dataset1_1389172627824_411632
            value = SUM(((java.lang.Integer)field_j49.getValue())); //$JR_EXPR_ID=41$
                    <->
3 errors

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:204)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:241)
```

I upgraded to latest Jasper version (5.5.0) but the result is the same.

Comment: can you show me your expression

Comment: You're right. I've added the jrxml to the question. The problem is in `<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[SUM($F{1})]]></textFieldExpression>`

Comment: what's this `<![CDATA[SUM($F{1})]]>` ..........1 is not a field name

Comment: yes, it is: `<field name="1" class="java.lang.Integer"/>`... same error with  `<field name="_1" class="java.lang.Integer"/>` so I don't think it's a field name problem

Comment: make it as any other name............

Comment: with another field name (also using a name without numbers) the problem remains

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44767/discussion-between-nidhishkrishnan-and-ste)

Comment: I solved the compilation problem changing the report language from Java to Javascript. Added the answer. Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

From [jaspersoft download][1]

[1]: http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/jr-ce-releases/net/sf/jasperreports/jasperreports-functions/5.5.0/ download the jasperreports-functions-5.5.0.jar and place it in your class path.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<field name="1" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
```

to

```
<field name="one" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
```

and assign the expression as

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[SUM($F{one})]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Comment: same result, it's not working. even `SUM((java.lang.Number)1)` result in a _The method SUM(Number) is undefined for.._ message

Comment: can you post the entire jrxml

Answer (score 0):

I solved the compilation problem changing the report language from Java to Javascript:

```
<jasperReport ... name="report_name" language="javascript" ...>
```

Comment: I was wrong, with javascript it compiles, but only because javascript is not compiled, but interpreted. The error appears at runtime.